Single-core-wires: should sharp turns be avoided?
When making connections with single-core wires, should sharp turns like this be avoided, opting for a rounder turn? Or it doesn't matter?


that does not look like a sharp bend

Sharper corners cause a very small number of electrons to accumulate (DC) and/or vary under AC so they can "bend" the current just right to bend around the corner perfectly (make the corner so to speak.) But it's only a few. At high frequency AC that process becomes an EM radiator. But it's not going to matter much here. By the time it does matter, a lot of other things will also matter to complicate things. So your brain will be in a different place, anyway. You're fine.

Unless you're dealing with GHz (and that would not likely be on a perfboard like that), the only concern I can think of would be damaging the insulation with your pliers bending it.
Otherwise if you like the way it looks, it's fine.

I'm working with an ESP32-C3 and HX711. So I don't think that's GHz?

Not even remotely close.
